# How to create subdirs on other server on same domain with SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm working on SQL script which task is transfer binary data (images, docs) stored in SQL Database hosted on one server to shared folder on another server in  the same domain. But also I want to create directory tree in this shared folder with SQL script, so I used this command with UNC path :

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir '//MYSERVER/sharedfoler/testdir/'
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 22048, Level 15, State 0, Line 0
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter
```

And my permissions are ok, becuase when I tried to transfer data to this shared folder it worked without problems. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: i think you need to specify whole path`EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir 'C:\MYSERVER\sharedfoler\testdir'`

Comment: @Slasko Thanks for advice but I need to use UNC path becuase shared folder is on different machine not on the same as my SQL Server but both are in same network domain. I think in that path isn't problem because I use same type of path for creation and transfer binary data from databse to the same  server where I want to create subdirs and for file transfer UNC path works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
--master.dbo.xp_create_subdir '\\MYSERVER\sharedfoler\testdir\'
--GRANT exec ON xp_cmdshell TO '<somelogin>'
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = '<other_login>';
GO
USE master;
xp_cmdshell 'md \\MYSERVER\sharedfoler\testdir\, NO_OUTPUT';
REVERT ;
```